# expansion of polynomials of higher degrees

Tags: calculus, polynomials

How to expand $(x-x_n)(x-x_{n-1})...(x-x_0)$ into $a_nx^n+...+a_0$? Surely, $a_n=1$ is equal to one in my case, but how to find out the rest of coefficients? Do we a numerical algorithm of calculating them?

Comment: See [Vieta's formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** To find all the coefficients of the expansion, you may consider what we call elementary symmetric polynomials:
$$e_k(x) = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \dots < i_k \leq n} x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\dots x_{i_k}.$$
Have a look here: [elementary symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial).